# Tomcat server is very slow without internet connection

Tags: tomcat

I am using Tomcat server for my web applications. When I am connected to the internet the app is fast, but when I'm not it is taking longer to open the application in the webbrowser. I am using Tomcat 6.0.37.

Comment: You need to check the network connections with your browser. Firefox Ctrl+Shift+Q, IE: F12.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some files getting downloaded online...please check your application.
Or use firebug to track the request from your application.

Comment: where i have to check these files

Comment: look into your applications code....or try running application from browser and then using firebug check if anything getting downloaded from internet or not